IntelliJ won't expand collapsed rows
Anytime I create the studentMenu() or profMenu() shown in the screenshot, IntelliJ collapses the rows in that method and will not let me expand them (both via Expand button in row number column or right click Foldering > Expand or Expand All).

I use these methods in my main() method, but this issue occurs even if I comment them out before and after creating these methods.
This is for a homework assignment.
Things I've tried:

Restarting IntelliJ multiple times
Committing changes in class where methods are created
Copying similar method and changing name
Writing new method from scratch
Changing access modifiers
Adding/removing static
Changing return type
Creating method with desired code
Creating method with no code
Removed all default Java auto-collapse boxes under Code Foldering setting
Created methods in different places within class (i.e. specific row numbers aren't the issue)

None of these attempts resolved the issues.

Try File | Manage IDE Settings | Restore Default Settings...: https://i.imgur.com/kbrkC7w.png. Update to the latest version. Could be caused by some plug-in. Check idea.log for possible exceptions when you try to expand the collapsed code and add the exception to your question.

These files are just text, so if you are really stuck, just open the files in a different editor.

I was facing the same issue today. I managed to make it work again after some tries (even though I really don't know what exactly the issue was).
I went to Settings -> Editor -> General -> Code Folding. There I was looking for a box which was checked but should not have been. I didn't find any. I then unchecked all boxes and it was still not working. Then I checked all the boxes again (clicked apply), unchecked them again (clicked apply) and then checked only those which I thought made sense (clicked apply again) and then it worked again.
I know this is not a high quality answer, but still it might help someone with the same issue.
